# Power BI connector to JIRA

Tags: jira, powerbi, jira-rest-api, powerbi-datasource

I am trying to access the api of JIRA to retrieve data from my database.

1- I click on web, put the url, click connect, but I get an 400 error (Bad request).

2- I tried then to set the authentication header to basic + user:pasword encoded in base64 code.
The next windows, ask me in which mode I want to access the web api:
- Anonymous: give me a bad request
- Basic authentication: tells me that I can't have both authenticaton header + basic authentication

Don't know how to get the data, anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting I found that I mustn't put in the API address

instead of `htts://my.jira.app:2990/rest/api/2/search`

input `https://my.jira.app:2990`

Select "basic" for authentication, enter your username (no encoding), and your password.

If it doesn't prompt for a username and a password (happens often), then you need to change it by going to your dataset settings, and updating the web credentials.